# rails file_field does not pass parameters to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<div class="modal-body">
                        <%= form_for :@hr_detail_avatar, url: hr_detaila_path, html: {role: "form", class: "form-horizontal", :multipart =>true}, method: :put do |form|%> 




                        <div class="form-group"> 
                            <label for="image" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Photo Code</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">


                              <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
                              <!--<input type="file" id="user_image" name="image[avatar]" />-->
                            </div>
                          </div>


                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="margin-left: 35%;">
                              <input type="submit" class= "buttons save"value="Save" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <button type="button" class="buttons cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        <% end %>
                      </div>
```

the file_field does not send the parameters to the controller.
The controller does not receive any parameters from the view and an error is shown stating that the parameters are empty.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: `<%= form_for :@hr_detail_avatar ....` -your form looks like this ?  `:@hr_detail_avatar` what is it ?? Is `@hr_detail_avatar` available to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the :avatar in the strong parameters . Also you need to check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm).

Comment: If it didn't help then tell me

Answer (score 0):

In your controller search where you have defined params.. I mean search for **params.require**

there inside `.permit()` include `:avatar`